# how to insert values in an sql table with uniqueidentifier column using vb?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a column with `uniqueidentifier, rowguidcol, not null, PK, default, and newsequentialid()` in a table. And I'm using VB to insert values in it, but i just can't.

[image: error message]

I tried adding columns but it still wont. This is my first time using `uniqueidentifier` since I've only used identity. So please help me.

Is there something i need to do that I don't know.? Thank you.

Comment: May be you missing Autoincrement of uniqueidentifier column .That means set true the property 'Is Identity' property of the column.Otherwise you should pass value of uniqueidentifier column

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ - identity and uniqueidentifier are entirely different and incompatible things.

Comment: You should use parameterised queries. You are open to being hacked by SQL injection. Please post the `CREATE TABLE` for `tblchat`

Comment: You dont need a DataAdapter to insert a row, DO use SQL Parameters rather than glue little bits of string together and if you want dates to act like dates use dates.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour] - dont post pictures of code, add the actual code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NEWID()` when inserting into a UniqueIdentifier column. Something like :

`INSERT INTO (UniqueIdentifierColumn,Name,Age) VALUES (NEWID(),'Banana','20')`

Comment: You should not do this where the column has a default of `newsequentialid` as the whole point of this is that you want the guids to be sequential not random to avoid fragmentation.